# Is it possible to deal with circular dependencies with templating with just two files (headers only)?

Tags: c++

I have run into a circular dependency issue when trying to simplify templating within a header-only library.

EventEntry.hpp

```
#include "Event.hpp"

template<class Typespec>
class EventEntry{
    EventEntry(int priority, Event<Typespec>&& event); 

    ...

    std::unique_ptr<Event<Typespec>> eventPtr;
}
```

Event.hpp

```
#include "EventEntry.hpp"

template<class Typespec>
class Event{
    ...

    virtual void render(EventEntry<Typespec>& entry, ...) = 0;
}
```

Prior to these changes, EventEntry had a second template parameter which was the base Event class, i.e.

Old EventEntry.hpp

```
template<class BaseEvent, class Typespec>
class EventEntry{
    EventEntry(int priority, BaseEvent event);
}
```

Is there a way to get around this without creating multiple files to separate forward declarations/etc? If that is the only solution I will simply keep the second template parameter.

Comment: No the only way forward is dependency inversion which also would require a third small header file. But what if you could turn things inside out? Have a priority queue of jobs which can call the render method themselves. Each job will then have to implement a job interface with two methods :  `virtual priority get_priority() const noexcept = 0;` and `virtual void render() noexcept = 0;`. You can then have templated job (or event) objects that you construct with template arguments and derive from your job interface (at least you will end up with a homogenous queue that way).

Comment: Is simply putting them in one file an option? It looks like these two classes are pretty tightly coupled, so maybe they should just be one `#include`. Is there a situation where a user of this library would want to include one but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

As long as `Event` does not need the complete definition of `EventEntry`, I don't see a problem with forward-declaring it:

```
template<class Typespec>
class EventEntry;

template<class Typespec>
class Event {
    virtual void render(EventEntry<Typespec>& entry, ...) = 0;
};
```

If the definition of one of the `Event` member functions requires the complete definition of `EventEntry`, you could just put it in another header (separate declarations and definitions).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a direct answer, but just to show you what C++ can do when you turn things inside out and don't rely on inheritance so much (but use the power of static polymorphism).

While coding I also found that using lambda expression really disentangle jobs even more from what they are actually doing (so you can also use the job_queue for other things than rendering).

Demo : https://onlinegdb.com/2x3feuKXT

```
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// job_itf.h
//
// a generic interface for things to execute in a priority queue
class job_itf
{
public:
    virtual void run() noexcept = 0;
    virtual int get_priority() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual ~job_itf() = default;

protected:
    job_itf() = default;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// job.h
// 
// implemenation for specific jobs
// in this case a job will contain a lambda function it can execute
// this means you can use lambda capture to capture all the data
// or references to data your job needs to execute.
//
// #incude <job_itf.h>
template<typename fn_t>
class job_t final :
    public job_itf
{
public:
    job_t(int priority, fn_t fn) :
        m_priority{priority},
        m_fn{fn}
    {
    }

    ~job_t() = default;

    void run() noexcept override
    {
        m_fn();
    }

    int get_priority() const noexcept override
    {
        return m_priority;
    }

private:
    int m_priority;
    fn_t m_fn;
};

// ordering needed to order jobs in a queue
bool operator<(const std::unique_ptr<job_itf>& rhs, const std::unique_ptr<job_itf>& lhs)
{
    return rhs->get_priority() < lhs->get_priority();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// job_queue.h
// a priority queue of jobs
// #include <job_itf.h>

class job_queue_t
{
public:
    template<typename fn_t>
    void add_job(int priority, fn_t fn)
    {
        m_jobs.emplace(std::make_unique<job_t<fn_t>>(priority,fn));
    }

    bool execute_next()
    {
        if (m_jobs.size() == 0ul) return false;

        auto& job = m_jobs.top();
        job->run();
        m_jobs.pop();

        return true;
    }

private:
    std::priority_queue<std::unique_ptr<job_itf>> m_jobs;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// your renderer

class renderer_t
{
public:
    void render_square(int size)
    {
        std::cout << std::format("square : {}\n",size);
    }
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// main.cpp
// #include <job_queue.h>
// #include <renderer.h>

int main()
{
    renderer_t renderer;
    job_queue_t jobs;

    jobs.add_job(1,[&]{renderer.render_square(1);});
    jobs.add_job(3,[&]{renderer.render_square(3);});
    jobs.add_job(2,[&]{renderer.render_square(2);});

    while (jobs.execute_next());

    return 0;
}
```